# Can I format tooltip strings in App Designer?

Tags: matlab, format, tooltip, matlab-app-designer

I am working on migrating a GUI from MATLAB GUIDE to App Designer (v2019b). In GUIDE, I could format the tooltip text by supplying an HTML string. This doesn't appear to work in App Designer. Is there any way to format the tooltip text in App Designer?

In particular, I'm looking to bold certain words and add line breaks to the tooltip. Here's an example of the formatting I used in GUIDE:

```
<html>Here's a description of a Table<br>
<b>Column1: </b> This is a description of Column1.<br>
<b>Column2: </b> This is a description of Column2.<br>
<b>Column3: </b> This is a description of Column3.
```

For an output that would look like:

> Here's a description of a Table
>       **Column1:**  This is a description of Column1.
>       **Column2:**  This is a description of Column2.
>       **Column3:**  This is a description of Column3.

Comment: "Is there any way to format the tooltip text in App Designer" - definitely (because UIFigures are web pages, and you can customize them pretty much any way you like). However, this depends on your MATLAB version and the exact effect you'd like to achieve. Please mention the relevant MATLAB version(s) and add some example of text you'd like to reproduce.

Comment: @Dev-iL Thanks, I've added some example code and indicated the version is 2019b.

Comment: Regarding multi-line, you can simply supply a string array or a cell array. As for the bold, I have no idea how to do this yet :(

Comment: @Dev-iL Yeah, I think that's what I've determined as well. I can't figure out how to set a cell in the App Developer, so I'm assuming it has to be done programmatically?